# Printf with carriage return

Tags: c, terminal

```
printf("Hello%cWorld\n", '\r');
```

Outputs:

```
World
```

Because `'\r'` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line

Can I trust that all terminals have this behavior?

Comment: I would expect _most_ terminals made in in the last 30 or 40 years behave that way, but not _all_.

Comment: For actual, real terminals (if such things still exist) it may also depend on hardware settings, and whether the `termcap` or similar is correctly configured.

Comment: Try the same example with `different words of different lengths` you will notice changes in shells.

Comment: "I would expect most terminals" -- these days, we use terminal emulators running in windows on monitors. How they behave depends entirely on software, not hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lib curses will tell you the capabilities of your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

.0x0d in ASCII encoding is '\r', in this case

```
printf("Hello%cWorld\n", 0x0d);
```

is equal to

```
printf("Hello\rWorld\n");
```

A common C programming error is to assume a particular encoding is in use when, in fact, another one holds.

However, it works on most computers as @Joachim Pileborg said.

BUT I suggest to use '\r' instead of 0x0d, for portability and the latter looks like a magic number, which makes others who read your code even yourself feel confused someday.